# Read variable length text line into list of parameters

Tags: python-3.x

I have constructed a [parser](https://github.com/SanPen/GridCal/blob/master/src/GridCal/Engine/IO/psse_parser.py) for the text files saved by a power system simulator.

Simplifying, the format of the text file is that every line represents an object, and to make things interesting, each line contains a variable amount of information.

A nice example of this is given in the manual:

> I, MODSW, ADJM, STAT, VSWHI, VSWLO, SWREM, RMPCT, RMIDNT, BINIT, N1,
>   B1, N2, B2, ... N8, B8

This line represents a switch object, and the parameters `N` and `B` are given by pairs incrementally. So any line representing a switch may have 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24 or 26 elements.

Right now I am going into this the hard way:

```
if len(line) == 12:
   I, MODSW, ADJM, STAT, VSWHI, VSWLO, SWREM, RMPCT, RMIDNT, BINIT, N1, B1 = line
elif len(line) == 14:
   I, MODSW, ADJM, STAT, VSWHI, VSWLO, SWREM, RMPCT, RMIDNT, BINIT, N1, B1, N2, B2 = line
elif ...
```

etc.

Is there a smarter way to parse a variable number of elements in a vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [assign to variable-length lists](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) by adding a `*` before an assignment target:

```
I, MODSW, ADJM, STAT, VSWHI, VSWLO, SWREM, RMPCT, RMIDNT, BINIT, *NBs = line
```

The `NBs` will be a `list` containing `N1, B1, N2, B2, ...` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

you can make function to accept dynamic length of parameters like below

```py
def dynamic_params(a, b, c, *params):
    print(params)

params = [i for i in range(10)]
dynamic_params("hello", "how", "are", "you", *params)

params = [i for i in range(15)]
dynamic_params("hello", "how", "are", "you", *params)
```

note how a,b,c take "hello", "how", "are" and then "you", *params are passed as params to the function

then you can collect the values from file in list and pass it to the function to process it.